# how to get data from <ul>,<li>l ist tags to scrape data

Tags: html, web-scraping, data-extraction

I have already extracted data from a webpage but i cannot able to extract data from webpage which does not have unique identifier

I have already tried to extract data from a webpage which has unique identifiers like class ,span ,id but what to do when the page doesn't have unique identifier

```
url="https://dblp.org/"
r=requests.get(url)
print(r.content)
b=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
print(b.prettify())
a=b.find_all('ul',{"id":"browsable"})  #no id is available
```

It actually shows None where the expected results should be a list of links available

Comment: what links are you after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) selector for `a` tags within `li` elements. Using the `body` parent tag as an example, you can then get the `li` elements child `a` `href`s with the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://dblp.org/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('body li a')]
print(links)
```

If must have parent `ul` tag then:

```
body ul li a
```

---

Worth noting two of the script tags in particular also contain a json structure with links available depending on your needs.